# How can I parse HTML table that holds different object types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML table that holds the following object types: text, textbox, listbox (select) and buttons (see the attached picture).
My purpose is to parse, where it is possible, the text from the table.

For instance, I would like to parse the User Name, Permission, SNMPv3 Auth and SNMPv3 Priv columns.
[image: The Table to Parse]

In the case of the listboxes, I already know how to collect the selected option text.
Tables that include only text are well known to me and I know how to parse them very well but the methods that I have used to parse them don't suit this kind of a table.

How would you suggest me to deal with this kind of a table?

In the code example I print the contents of the table (the text), but actually, I will store it for the purpose of analyzing the contents of it. By the way, you can also see that I am not referring to the first row (the header) of the table.

This is how the users view list rows which has only div tag
[image]

Comment: I think you should add the HTML of the table for a good answer...

Comment: Share `table` HTML source along with the code you've tried

Comment: We are not clear what's your meaning of parse the UserName ... columns. Please give example to explain.

Comment: My purpose is to scan the table, line by line, and tell for instance that a user that is named "user1" with "Read only User" permissions and certain SNMPV3 attributes was defined

Comment: By the way in this case Password and Edit User columns are not important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the html you have shared, each tr has three elements, text box, selectbox and button.

Also in the screen shot for the saved record, I don't see input field. For example, the text user1. I assume the user1 is inside a span tag.
like

```html
<td>
 <div>user1</div>
</td>
```

You have to handle each element differently to get the value out of it.

- To get innerText in div, we have to use `elem.text`
- To get attribute
  value of input text box, we have to use `elem.get_attribute('value')`
- To get the selected value, we have to use `Select(elem).first_selected_option`

This is an example code, to get the data of your dom. Please free to edit as per your need.
I have used css selectors to find elements. Look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for the syntax.

```py
# This returns all the tr elements in the table
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#sec_user_table>tbody>tr")
for i in range(1, len(rows)):
    # This returns only the span, input which is not password and select elements
    cols = rows[i].find_elements_by_xpath("td//*[self::div[not(.//input)] or self::input[@type='text'] or self::select]")
    for col in cols:
        if col.tag_name == 'SELECT':
            print(Select(col).first_selected_option.text) # To get the select value
        elif col.tag_name == 'INPUT':
            print(col.get_attribute('value'))    # To get the input value
        else:
            print(col.text)    # To get text fron span
```

Or

**Simple solution with single selectors:**

This is specific to your case as you dont required input element completely

```
  # This returns all the tr elements in the table
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#sec_user_table>tbody>tr")
    for i in range(1, len(rows)):
        username = rows[i].find_element_by_xpath("//div[not(.//input)]")
        print(username.text)

        select = rows[i].find_elements_by_css_selector("select")
        for col in cols:
            print(Select(col).first_selected_option.text) # To get the select value
```

Comment: I got the following error message: 'TypeError: 'dict' object cannot be interpreted as an integer' It seems like rows.size results in a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah. Updated the code to get length of rows. Element size is actually method to get rect coordinates.

Comment: I am sorry, but this still doesn't work. I get a "TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()"

Comment: oops. typo. used find_element_ instead of find_elements_. Check the updated code now

Comment: ' cols' has the same type I guess ?

Comment: By fixing the typo in cols I still don't get the result. All the contents of the listboxes is printed and the User Name column content is not printed at all

Comment: Great. I assumed that user name column is inside span. Can you add the html of the td which is holding user name in question?

Comment: I added above a screen capture that shows the html code for the exact same table above. By the way, I thought that by using the Select and ' first_selected_option' I will catch only the option that was selected. Why do I still get all the options from the listbox ?

Comment: Thanks a lot but your last update also doesn't do the job. But, thanks to your help I was first introduced with the option to use the css selector with it options. I will add my solution and you can see what I mean. By the way, it still needs a little tweak I need to make it ignore of the last row

Comment: No change. You still print the whole list box and for some reason you print the table twice

Comment: oops. i have not used the rows variable instead it was referring  to usertable. Please join the chat

Comment: Still the same. It is not doing the required job. You go over the table three times

Comment: Finally i found the issue and updated the locator in mulitple xpath code :)

Comment: Verified in local with dom. Works 100%

Answer (score 0):

I improved the above solution to solve my specific problem, it still may need some tweaks, for instance I will need to think of a way to ignore the last line, but this is not a big issue. Another thing that I want to fix is the time that it takes to get the result. For some reason it takes several seconds

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#sec_user_table>tbody>tr")
for row in rows:
   cols = row.find_elements_by_css_selector("div,select")
   for col in cols:
       if col.tag_name == 'div':
           if col.text != '':
               print(col.text)
       elif col.tag_name == 'select':
           print(Select(col).first_selected_option.text)
```

Comment: Do you no need to get the input field of username at add area?

Comment: As we are taking all the div, it will loop with all div element. So there may be slowness. In general practice, we have restrict the element selection with in locators.